# MSBuild syntax for using another PropertyReferences item in a .NET function invocation

Tags: msbuild

I want to define a `Timestamp` property and use it to drive the value of several other properties, as the intent is shown below:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
    <TrapHouseBuildToolsPath>..\TrapHouse.Build.NetStandard\bin\$(Configuration)\netstandard2.0\publish\TrapHouse.Build.NetStandard.dll</TrapHouseBuildToolsPath>

    <Timestamp>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToUniversalTime()))</Timestamp>
    <DeploymentEnvironment>LOCALDEV</DeploymentEnvironment>
    <TrapHouseVersion>$(DeploymentEnvironment)$([System.String]::Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", Timestamp)</TrapHouseVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In one of my tasks I spit out the value of `TrapHouseVersion`, which is not what I expect:

```
4.5.0-LOCALDEV$([System.String]::Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", Timestamp)
```

It seems pretty clear that I am not getting the syntax right, but I have had difficulty finding good resources for this sort of thing.

What do I need to do to get the `TrapHouseVersion` to evaluate properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing a closing brace at the end, but also know that the property isn't persisted as `DateTime` but properties are only stored as strings, so you can't use `String.Format` later on (except for parsing `$(Timestamp)` to a `DateTime` again):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="PrintVersion">
   <PropertyGroup>
    <Timestamp>$([System.String]::Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToUniversalTime())))</Timestamp>
    <DeploymentEnvironment>LOCALDEV</DeploymentEnvironment>
    <TrapHouseVersion>$(DeploymentEnvironment)$(Timestamp)</TrapHouseVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PrintVersion">  
    <Message Importance="high" Text="TrapHouseVersion: $(TrapHouseVersion)" />
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

When run:

```
$ dotnet msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  TrapHouseVersion: LOCALDEV20181012171759
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and solution. I didn't realize that properties were only stored as strings, so I guess I will need to be parsing the Timestamp where I need it as a date again. Also, thanks for the easy way to determine the value of the property.

Comment: Aside from that: do note that when you start basing versions (possibly also assembly and NuGet versions) on seconds, you'll end up with projects that may never be "up-to-date" and always have high build times.. personally I try to base versions on commit counts (e.g. using [this library](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning))

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - that makes a lot of sense. I am unfortunately using mercurial for this project but maybe there is a similar tooling available. Since I have your attention, I wanted to ask another question - if your custom tasks are in the same solution in another project, whats the best way to reference the assembly or namespace you need? I tried doing a ProjectReference and using `AssemblyName`, but it didn't work - only by publishing the library project and referencing by `AssemblyFile` does it seem to find it

Comment: Depends on where in the project the task is needed.. if it can run after `ResolveProjectReferences`, p2p references (with `ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"`) could be used and you can hard-code some target path to the other project's output. But I suggest separating task development completely into a separate solution and distribute via NuGet. makes it easier (e.g. https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk)